# How do I access FooBox lightbox jQuery Events API?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The FooBox docs say it's possible to hook into FooBox events using code like

```
jQuery('.fbx-instance').on('foobox.afterLoad', function(e) {
   alert(e.fb.item.url);
});
```

I'm not having any luck. I've tried putting this code inside the jQuery(document).ready() function and outside it and nothing's working. Has anyone had luck with this? Where does the code go?

Here's the page in the docs: http://docs.fooplugins.com/foobox/developers/foobox-jquery-events/

Answer (score 0):

Their docs site doesn't seem to be responding, but try this, let me know if it works:

```
(function ($) {
    $(function () {
        var myFoo = $('.fbx-instance').foobox({
            afterLoad: function (e) {
                alert("Hey I am loaded!");
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work. I ended up purchasing the Pro version which supports this.